# setFilesToUpload appear to not be working when we need to upload a directory

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have this method:

```
public static async performUpload(): Promise<boolean> {
    await t.switchToIframe(monitorLandingPage.functionalMonitoringIframe)
    await t.click(uploadingPage.uploadButton)
    await t.setFilesToUpload(uploadingPage.fileUploader, ['../../resources/1/'])
    await t.wait(WaitConfig.Waits.mediumWait)
    return
}
```

The call to `setFilesToUpload` appears to not be working.

html code

```
<div class="DefaultTheme__file-uploader___2MsDp src-components-new-UploadMonitorForm-UploadMonitorForm__uploader--3P2Fu" data-anypoint-component="FileUploader" title=""><input id="file-uploader-input" type="file" directory="true" webkitdirectory="true" style="display: none;"><span class="DefaultTheme__filename___3HYkz DefaultTheme__empty___3CjFP" id="file-uploader-file-name">Choose monitor folder</span><button id="file-uploader-button" aria-invalid="false" type="button" class="button DefaultTheme__file-uploader-button___1PVKm DefaultTheme__button___29mtS DefaultTheme__tertiary___3cLHz DefaultTheme__no-fill___1Pw4q" data-anypoint-component="Button"><span class="button-children DefaultTheme__children___WfQFi">Choose folder</span></button></div>
```

Generated

Comment: we are using redux-thunk for upload and test cafe version is 1.8.8

Comment: I also tried to pass each file on the directory as follows: await t.setFilesToUpload(uploadingPage.fileUploader, ['../../resources/1/bat.yaml,../../resources/1/main.dw,'])

Comment: Browser chrome not headless

Answer (score 0):

At present, it is not possible to upload a directory. There is a suggestion in the TestCafe repository about this: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3206.

Comment: You can see a detailed [description](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html) of how to test file upload in TestCafe and inspect a runnable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/upload-files).